is there a way to control the bone of a character manually?
Is there a way to control the bone of a humanoid character manually via script. ?
I know that I can use something like two bone IK for this purpose, like in this picture.

however that kinda limits the movement of the root, mid and tip as it is totally depended on the target position.
what i would like to achieve is to move a bone independently without any restriction of dependencies on the target

Transforms are transforms... you can always jsut modify their values. You won't get good results trying to do that at the same time as you have an animation or IK going though - its one or the other. If it's under an animator's control then you shouldn't be touching it. If you need really fine control then writing your own super basic IK solver isn't crazy dificult.
